# Mysterious TypeError using Python and NumPy C-API

Tags: c, multithreading, python-2.7, numpy, python-c-api

I am writing a Python script, extended with C for computationally intensive portions of code.

Most of the data passed between Python and C is contained in NumPy arrays. These arrays are attributes of some object `dataobject`. In addition, some constants and parameters are also provided to the C routines. These are collected in `dict` attributes of another object, `dictobject`.

Several calculations are performed this way:

1. pre-allocate NumPy arrays in Python, as attributes of `dataobject`
2. pass `dataobject` and `dictobject` to C for calculations, writing into above-mentioned arrays
3. check/visualise `dataobject` data in Python

The first call to one of my C functions (a calculation) runs without any problems. I can manipulate the pre-allocated NumPy arrays containing the data generated in C in Python without encountering errors.

After my second call to C (another calculation), all hell breaks loose:

```
TypeError: a float is required in 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1160, in currentThread
   return _active[_get_ident()]
```

This error is traced back to the following line, practically the next action in my Python script:

```
logger.info("some constant string ... ")
```

This looks very magic. What does and error thrown by `_get_ident()` imply? What does a call to the `logging` module have to do with anything!?

After some testing, it seems that most operations requiring some form of iteration over *anything* (`for`, `reduce`, etc.) will result in the same `TypeError: a float is required` ... EXCEPT if, before continuing, I iterate over ANY slice of ANY of the arrays I have sent to C, even ones that I had sent in my previous calculation (also part of `dataobject`)! In this case, execution proceeds normally: the data in `dataobject` and `dictobject` is completely correct.

The "caller" (Python) code for every such calculation has an equivalent of the following structure:

```
def mycalculation(dataobject, dictobject):
    dataobject.arr1 = np.zeros(size, dtype=float, order='C')
    #   ...
    dataobject.arrn = np.zeros(size, dtype=float, order='C')

    dictobject.dict1 = {'size' = 10, 'some_parameter' = 2 }
    #   etc, for multiple dict attributes containing multiple parameters

    my_c_module.py2cfunction(dataobject, dictobject)
    #   wrapper for calculations in C

    return None
```

The "wrapper" (C/C++) code for every such calculation has the following structure:

```
static PyObject* py2c_function( PyObject *self, PyObject *args ) {

    PyObject* py_dataobj = NULL ;    
    PyObject* py_dictobj = NULL ;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO",
                &py_dataobj,
                &py_dictobj ))
        return NULL ;

     my_datastruct data ;
    /* typedefed */

    if (!get_datastruct(py_dataobj, &data) == ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        Py_INCREF(Py_None) ;
        return Py_None ;
    }
    /* get some arrays - attributes of dataobject (py_dataobj) - in a struct
    (as C arrays, using PyArray_DATA) */

    my_dictstruct dict ;
    /* typedefed */

    if (!get_dictstruct(py_dictobj, &dict) == ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        Py_INCREF(Py_None) ;
        return Py_None ;
    }
    /* get some entries of dicts - attributes of dictobject (py_dictobj) - in a struct 
    (as C types, e.g. using PyDict_GetItem, then PyFloat_asDouble) */

    calculation_func(&data, &dict) ;
    /*  send to pure C CODE (no more Python-C-API magic in the rest of the code) */

    Py_INCREF(Py_None) ;
    return Py_None ; 
}
```

Where the functions `get_*struct` access attributes of `py_*obj` and store them in `my_*struct`.

The program breaks clearly right after the second call to C, although it is exteremely similar in structure to the first - could this be the result of a memory leak in my C libraries? Using `Py_REFCNT`, it seems the reference counting checks out for `py_dictobj` and `py_dataobj`...

How can my C extension break `_get_ident()`, which seems to refer to `thread.get_ident()` from `import thread` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.get_ident))? Could you help me narrow down the possible causes of this mysterious and frustrating problem?

Comment: For this sort of question you really have to provide a [mcve]. My suspicion is that a Python error is being raised somewhere in `get_datastruct` or `get_dictstruct`, you aren't checking for it here, and so instead the error appears to have been raised in `thread` (the next place it gets checked for). Unfortunately, without a complete example we'll never know.

Comment: Approaching problem from another direction. If your C code does not have any external native library dependencies and mostly focused on intensive array iterations with some math involved, I'd suggest taking a look at [Cython](http://cython.org/). `cdef` with `nogil` considerably boosts performance, additionaly there is a nice report available on how much C action hides behind your cython code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. @DavidW, this is what I suspected. I will try to isolate the portion of code that is problematic to present a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. More information to come soon.

Comment: Adding a few `PyErr_Occurred()` calls in your code might help you track down where it first goes wrong.

Comment: @DavidW, you were right about the origin of the error. I was not checking the inputs correctly in my `get_*struct` functions. Your suggestions were critical in helping me find it! How do you suggest I modify my question so that you may compile your comments into an answer that I can reward?

Comment: @aagastaldi I don't think there's a great value in retrospectively trying to change the question - it's probably best to just let it go unanswered (and hopefully learn to how ask a more complete question for next time!)